# Determine the consumption for a new voyage of 15% increased distance, at an increased speed of 5% and with the mass reduced by 10%?

Tags: calculus, percentages

The fuel consumption for a ships voyage varies directly was the (mass of the ship)^2/3  , varies directly as the (speed of the ship)^2 and varies directly as the distance of the voyage.

For a particular voyage a ship has a fuel consumption of 250 tonne.
Determine the consumption for a new voyage of 15% increased distance, at an increased speed of 5% and with the mass reduced by 10%

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is it from a book or class?  If so, are there previously solved problems, worked examples, or theorems, (i.e. **tools**) from the book or class that led up to this problem?  If so, are you having trouble applying these tools?  If so, what tools (i.e. training) have you been given that led up to this problem, and what difficulties/confusion are you having, applying these tools?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the mass of the ship to be "M", the speed to be "S", and the distance of the voyage to be "D", the fuel consumption is $FC= KM^{2/3}S^2D$ for some constant, K.

For "15% increased distance, at an increased speed of 5% and with the mass reduced by 10%" D changes to 1.15D, S changes to 1.05S and mass changes to 0.90M.
4
The fuel consumption changes to $K(0.90M)^{2/3}(1.05S)^2(1.15D)= (kM^{2/3}S^2D)((0.90^{2/3})(1.05^2)(1.15))$.